# Getting values without using intersection

Tags: mysql

I need to write a SQL query to find the *customer number* of *customers* who have made more than 3 payments and made a single payment of more than $70,000.

Here is what I have come up with so far which only groups the *customerNumber's* who have ALL payments over 70000. **I am not allowed to use intersection.**

```
SELECT customernumber FROM CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS
where amount > 70000
group by customerNumber
having count(*) > 3
```

Comment: `where` applies as rows are being considered, individually, for inclusion in the result set. the `>70k` requirement applies to the results as a whole, which means it should be in a `having` clause, which gets applied just before results are sent out to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the predicate to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT customernumber 
FROM CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS
GROUP BY customerNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN amount > 70000 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

The conditional aggregate of `COUNT` in `HAVING` clause captures `customerNumber` groups having a single row with `amount > 70000`.

Comment: That did print out people with more than 3 payments and 1 greater than 70000, but it only printed out 3, when there is 13, any ideas why?

Comment: @JohnDoe Can you setup an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demo with some sample data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: That was my fault, your code was right, I should have said made AT LEAST 1 payment of 70,000 or more. All I had to do was add a > sign. My apologies, thanks for your help